# PHP regex not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I'm trying to extract some values in an array based on them being alpha numeric or having an underscore. It is not working through. This is what I'm providing the script:

```
...
  [183]=>
  string(23) "/games/boomerang_devils"
  [184]=>
  string(26) "/games/krushuna_waterfalls"
  [185]=>
  string(21) "/games/super_drift_3d"
  [186]=>
  string(34) "/games/around_the_world_in_80_days"
  [187]=>
  string(24) "/games/governor_of_poker"
  [188]=>
  string(21) "/games/shoot_on_sight"
...
```

The code:

```
if (preg_match('/\/games\/[a-zA-Z0-9_]/', $array['item'])) {
    // Add to DB
}
```

But it's not picking it up. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_] is one character only.
```

you need to repeat the character by adding `+`

```
if (preg_match('/\/games\/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/', $array)) 
{
    // Add to DB
}
```

Comment: Should match without the `+` as well. That's not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

[`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg_match) does not work on your `$array` variable. It expects a string. So either loop over your list, and test each string. Or use [`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/preg_grep) to filter your array for matching entries.

Other than that, you forgot the quantifier `+`

```
 /\/games\/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/
```

Possibly also subject start `^` and `$` end anchors. And `\w` could supplant your character list.

Comment: If you only want a partial string match, then the original question's regex is completely adequate.

Comment: True, not relevant. I was presuming an exact match with `^` and `$`. But OPs main issue is probably the variable usage (and disabled `error_reporting` that is).

Comment: I was checking within a loop turns out there was an error in my SQL that's why it wasn't getting added to the database.